# UITableView not scrolling on becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I know there are a number of questions on stack overflow on this topic but I haven't been able to find an answer to my specific problem. I have a UITableView with multiple sections. Each cell has a UITextField that is given a tag. In my textFieldShouldReturn function I have a switch statement that calls the next cell's textField to become the first responder based on it's tag.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

switch (textField.tag) {
    case FIRST_NAME_FIELD_TAG:
        [_catv.lastNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        break;
    case LAST_NAME_FIELD_TAG:
        [_catv.emailTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        break;
    case EMAIL_FIELD_TAG:
        [_catv.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        break;
    case PASSWORD_FIELD_TAG:
        [_catv.phoneNumberTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        break;
    case PHONE_NUMBER_FIELD_TAG:
        [_catv.phoneNumberTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [self createAccount];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return NO;
```

}

Everything works perfectly until I get to a point where the cells are below the keyboard (not visible). Then the return doesn't seem to do anything though it IS getting called. If I manually scroll to the next cell, only then does the cell become the first responder. I'm looking to have the cell be scrolled above the keyboard automatically. I'm thinking the issue might be the separating header view at the beginning of each section but I just can't tell. Any insight would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not be optimal solution, but since UITableView inherits UIScrollView, have you considered scrolling to the appropriate cell programmatically and then assigning responder?

Perhaps try:

```
[_tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT)
                           animated:YES];
```

Comment: I ended up going with scrollToRowAtIndexPath, getting the indexPath of the cell that the textField is in but its the same idea.